# How to parse values from a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, file

I'm trying to get the values from the json file and the error that I'm getting is `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. I'm parsing the file correctly and moreover I guess my json file format is also correct. Where I'm going wrong?

Both the files are in the same directory.

**Main_file.py**

```
import json

json_data = open('meters_parameters.json')

data = json.loads(json_data)  // TypeError: expected string or buffer
print data
json_data.close()
```

**meters_parameters.json**

```
{
    "cilantro" : [{
        "cem_093":[{
            "kwh":{"function":"3","address":"286","length":"2"},
            "serial_number":{"function":"3","address":"298","length":"2"},
            "slave_id":{"function":"3","address":"15","length":"2"}
        }]
    }],
    "elmeasure" : [{
        "lg1119_d":[{
            "kwh":{"function":"3","address":"286","length":"2"},
            "serial_number":{"function":"3","address":"298","length":"2"},
            "slave_id":{"function":"3","address":"15","length":"2"}
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: You meant `json_data.close()`, right?

Comment: Oops. Typo. Yes it is `json_data.close`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`loads` expects a string not a file handle. You need `json.load`:

```
import json

with open('meters_parameters.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print data
```

Comment: Arg, forgot about `json.load`! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load the file object, when you want to load everything *in* the file. Do:

```
data = json.loads(json_data.read())
```

`.read()` gets everything from the file and returns it as a string.

---

A `with` statement is much more pythonic here as well:

```
with open('meters_parameters.json') as myfile:
    data = json.loads(myfile.read())
```